# Best practise to use bottom navigation in android: activity vs fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, bottomnavigationview

I am coming from iOS and working to port an iOS app on android. In iOS there is the storyboard where you can connect different view (activities) and embed them into tab bars and navigation bars. I am having an issue to understand what is the best way to implement bottom navigation in android...

Let say I have 3 bottom navigation items with the following

1. tab1

   - page1.1

     - page1.2
2. tab2

   - page2.1

     - page2.2

       - page2.3
3. tab3

   - page3.1

     - page3.2

       - page3.3

As an example in tab1 I have page1.1. Then let say I have a button in page1.1 which bring me in page1.2. If I go back from page1.2 I want to go back to page1.1. Same story for page2.1, I can go to page 2.2 and from page2.2 I can go to page2.3. I also want to go from page3.2 to page 1.2

I have read fragments are the best way to do it (each page.x is to become a different fragment with a different layout) but it does not seem very easy. I have also read I can use activities but many suggest not to use it

What do you recommend that I focus on? Are there any other solution to consider on top of fragment and activities? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Fragments with a Single Activity. If you don't, you will have to *copy*/*include* one bottom bar in multiple Activities. It might be useful in some cases however when Activity is switched, your bar will redraw which might turn out to be a bad user experience.

> I have read fragments are the best way to do it (each page.x is to become a different fragment with a different layout) but it does not seem very easy

Using Fragments might actually make it easier than if you use Activities. If you use Fragments, you can have one Activity be in control of every fragment that is being displayed, meaning that you can control navigation based on which fragment is being shown. This way, you can handle some special scenarios that do not fall into usual navigation behavior. 
Doing the same in Activities would be a little more difficult since you'd have to continuously pass around data in Intents and it would be difficult to control the behavior since your logic will be spread across Activities.

> What do you recommend that I focus on? Are there any other solution to consider on top of fragment and activities?

These two are only recommended solutions. If some of your UI elements are same in all pages while some part of it is changed constantly, then its best to use Fragments with single Activity. For screens that are completely different or that are not part of your navigation flow, you add more Activities for them instead of Fragments.
For example, You can use Fragments in One Activity with Bottom Navigation Bar, but for settings screen or profile screen, you should make separate Activites.

Comment: Hello Many thanks ! If you would need to do an app like Facebook (multiple tabs, multiple navigation pages for each tab) would you rather use fragments or activities?

Comment: @mactrix for the main dashboard, I would use One Activity that contains fragments, for settings, profile screen I would use Activities.

Comment: @mactrix Fragments cannot be used independently, they must be added to an Activity. Read more here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Comment: Thanks. Yes I understand. There must be an underlying activity to support Fragments. Ok so I will go with 1 activities and as many fragment as I can. This is likely going to be 20 fragments. Do you know if I will have problems to hold all these fragment in the memory. I basically would like that each tab will keep memory of the all fragments so that I can switch to one tab to another and see the latest fragment (I do not want to recreate fragments every time and reload data)

Comment: @mactrix only one fragment will be loaded and visible at a time so there is no issue. Don't keep reference to every fragment.
Now, you said there are 20 fragments, if their layout is same and content is different than why don't you use 1 fragment and pass it different data each time?

Comment: @mactrix or you can consider identical fragments as single fragment with different data